# flutter column values use to return arrray

Tags: arrays, flutter, flutter-widget

flutter datacolumn i m using column header value in direct function

like this

```
List<String> columnList = ['Name', 'age', 'Type','Expiry Date'];
```

how to write a function to return this columnList as array

I want to use like

```
List<String> columnList = columnList();
```

columnList function how to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your purpose, but if you want a return type, plz check below.

```
List<String> columnList() {
   return ['Name', 'age', 'Type','Expiry Date'];
}
```

Then, you can use "columnList()".

Comment: also, you can use it another way List<String> get columnList {
   return ['Name', 'age', 'Type','Expiry Date'];
}

Answer (score 0):

Dart arrays are actually Lists. So columnList here is an array too. Simple return it as array